# Is my new car engine damaged?

Tags: engine, nissan

I bought New Nissan 2 months ago. I was driving on down hills but as it was late at night and no car on the road, I enjoyed of high speed (4-5 min) and I didn't use the break . When we reached my husband was very angry and complained because he saw lots of smoke from my car while he was driving behind me. He said you damaged the engine because still car was cold (short drive).
I would like to know in this case what happened to the engine and what was the reason for the smoke? and really is too bad for engine if I don't use break in down hills (I always thought is better for engine)? Also he said new car you shouldn't go high speed at least for 5-6 months. Is that right?

Comment: Is it a diesel?

Comment: What do you consider "high speed". How many miles are on your vehicle now? Did he say where the smoke was coming from (tail pipe or otherwise)?

Comment: I would not be surprised it if was a diesel.

Comment: No it is not diesel. My concern is not high speed or mileage, I just like to know why there was smoke and what is happening to engine in this case? and I believe smoke was from cars exhaust.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you didn't come close to redlining the tac (high RPM) and it doesn't smoke now, you are probably ok.  Engines are not what they use to be, they last a lot longer and are made of improved materials.  Break-in time isn't a critical as it once was.

Comment: What information is this based on, that new engines last a lot longer than old ones?

Comment: Thanks Clinton, I did not come to red line, and I didn't press gas for high speed, I simply didn't use the break. So is that bad for engine? Because this is my daily road and I like to know more about how it is effect to engine in this case. Does that smoke mean oil was burning?

Comment: Are  you sure it just wasn't condensation because you started it up in the morning?

Comment: Usually smoke I think when you are decelerating,  using engine as break I think creates greater engine vacuum, maybe, if it is smoke you have something going on with your head,  valve train area.

Comment: Are you sure it was smoke and not just cold exhaust? It's more visible on cold mornings because the water doesn't evaporate before exiting the tailpipe.